why continuous derivatives are required for integration by parts
In integration by parts of u(x) integrated over v(x), u(x) and v(x) need to have continuous derivatives. Why?

Have you looked at a proof? Do it and then come back and ask about specific parts.

@md2perpe I think it's difficult to try to prove something that can't be proven.
I'm pretty new to math stack exchange but this doesn't seem like such a bad question.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

@SwitchArio. Why do you think that the integration by parts formula cannot be proven?

I meant that in integration by parts $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ don't need to have continuous derivatives, but you kinda asked him to try to prove they do need it. Let me know what you think

@SwitchArio. I didn't ask him to prove that. I meant that he should look at the proof of the integration by parts formula and see where the continuous derivatives come in.
